# How to make cross-platform apps?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flash

I am working to build my first apps, and I have completed a flash (action script) app that actually plays on my Android phone. It's just a piano like a hundred other pianos out there, but still.

I've done a lot of research, but I think the type of apps a person wants to make will mean they have to use certain platforms to build them rather than others (for example, if I was just building a website information app I could use Appy Pie or something).

I want to make a better piano to start. One that has lots of keys and the keys have good play functionality (touch responsive quality). I think I can code these already in either flash or javascript, but I've heard Apple iOs doesn't play javascript, and flash is a bit slow, it seems like, and might be limited in that way.

Any app-type specific advice on how I could make apps for all 3 platforms (preferably, at once?)

Comment: iOS doesn't do *Flash*, not JavaScript.

Comment: So JavaScript apps will work well on any device then?

Comment: Well they'll work as well as they work, and there's more than one way to make a "JavaScript app".

Comment: You say you have the trial version of flash? Ok more later...  And you have `...completed a flash (as3) app that actually plays on my Android phone`? Did this actually install as Android app? Did you have to make Android icons & set permissions before exporting APK? You have Java SDK and the Android SDK installed fine? Are you really just running an SWF file on Android? (thats not an app, thats for web browsers with Flash plugin). I want to show you the steps from Flash IDE to APK file but can't since the question is on hold (from non-Flash knowing admins, who wouldn't know how to...)

Comment: Just to be sure did you do it **[like in this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L0b13.png)**? You did all that & specified your app's icon (to tap on after installing)? Its a similar process for iOS (only no need to have the Android SDK installed etc). Just dont run SWF on mobiles (Adobe stopped that a long time ago and introduced those two buttons in picture to make genuine apps)

Comment: I did have to set permissions, but not an icon (optional), and published it as an APK, which I file transferred to my phone and ran it.

Thanks for this information though, VC.One

Comment: So whats the problem with now exporting same code to iOS? You used one button to make Android now use the other button...

Answer (score 1):

Google phonegap.builder that's the answer.
Phonegap builder makes the app in the 3 different platforms, Ios, Android and windows mobile.

Comment: That looks really great, and I'm already using the Adobe trial so I can try it out. I'll come back here and check this if it works best. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flash is being supported less and less - I wouldn't count on it as a cross-platform tool going forward. If you want a different option, look into game engines like Unity https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download or GameMaker http://www.yoyogames.com/studio- these are build once deploy anywhere.

I have had good success with GameMaker personally, getting it to build for web, ios, android, and windows.  The language is similar to as3, there's built in support for touch input, animation and 3rd party api connections, and a large modern community of developers that can help you make the switch.  You can try a free version out to get a feel for it.  Unity is also free to download, though you might find the learning curve a bit higher. It also might be overkill for a 2d piano app.

Comment: Using a "game engine" is an option, you're right. Like you say, it might be more than I need (and more work to learn), since the next step in this project is just a simple 2D piano. I would like to have really good touch sensitivity, though, so maybe game engines would do this better. I'm not sure. Javascript might do this well too, though. Not sure about it.